# how remove innerpadding of textbutton flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

How to remove internal spacing from a text button in flutter?

[image]

Remove the internal spacing of the button

```
TextButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                    EdgeInsets.zero),
                    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
              ),
              
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xffF6F6F7),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                  child: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
                  ))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the child has fixed size, you can remove padding through **making the `TextButton` to be as big as its child:**

just set :

```
minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(50,50)),
```

note: keep padding set to zero

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use a text button, It seems you are supposed to use an icon button here.
The text button itself shows no boundary (shows shadow only on hover), there you can set the padding to any value below 4 to reduce the gap. Although usually it's not recommended to place anything that close to a button.